# Can't apply styles to dynamically created nodes

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I created a custom element and I take html from its `<content>` and on `created` I use `Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(paperItem)` (`paperItem` was created via iteration on HTML I'd received from `<content>`) to insert that into local DOM. Well, I can't style `<paper-item>` from template's `<style>` tag no matter what I do. Even `Polymer.updateStyles();` doesn't help. What am I getting wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) explain how to apply styles to *distributed children*.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
  :host {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  #child-element {
    background: yellow;
  }
  /* styling elements distributed to content (via ::content) requires */
  /* selecting the parent of the <content> element for compatibility with */
  /* shady DOM . This can be :host or a wrapper element. */
  .content-wrapper > ::content .special {
    background: orange;
  }
</style>

<div id="child-element">In local DOM!</div>
<div class="content-wrapper"><content></content></div>

 </template>

  <script>

      Polymer({
          is: 'my-element'
      });

  </script>

</dom-module>

  <my-element>
    <div class="special">Here will have a different css </div>
 </my-element>
```